# Does Magento 1.9.x cron script, scans whole `shell` directory and executes all files inside of that folder?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, cron, third-party-module, shell

This is kind of confusion instead of Question that I have.

If I have added a new php script called `new.php` inside `shell` directory, then if I have already setup `cron.php` to run at specific intervals, then would that already execute `shell/new.php` or do I have to specify it somewhere else in the custom module to which `new.php` belongs ?

Glad if somebody could guide me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in your title: No.

Instead it reads the modules configuration where class methods are defined as jobs, together with their own schedule.

Inchoo documented it in this blog post: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-configurable-cron/

> Cron itself is more or less straightforward. As seen in the code
>   below, it is defined in a config.xml file with two main parts:
>   schedule and a method to be ran. A sample below shows a cron job named
>   “my_cron” that runs “doSomething” method inside the observer file
>   every five minutes. If you’re not familiar with the cron schedule
>   format, there’s a bunch of the articles and cron generators on the
>   internet.
>
> ```
> <config>
>     <crontab>
>         <jobs>
>             <my_cron>
>                 <schedule>
>                     <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
>                 </schedule>
>                 <run>
>                     <model>mymodule/observer::doSomething</model>
>                 </run>
>             </my_cron>
>         </jobs>
>     </crontab>
> </config>
> ```

There is more in the post, but this is what you need to get started. You should not write your cronjobs as PHP scripts, but as classes in a module.

Comment: Your answer is indeed explanatory and very true so accpeted it, though some part of answer I knew, but what confuses me is I have purchased a third party module which has it's own cron job defined and declared in `config.xml` and also a file is created in `shell` folder which calls that same module's model function which is also configured inside it's config.xml cron, so do I need to add that file separately as cron job in cPanel besides `cron.php` ?

Comment: No. Apparently that file is used to conveniently run this job manually from the shell **instead** of using a cronjob.

Comment: Ok will add to cPanel separate job then, thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: That is not necessary if the same function is already run via `config.xml` cronjob